# Arduino Twitter

Tags: arduino, ethernet, twitter

How do you send a tweet via Arduino using an Arduino Ethernet Shield?

Comment: **What does the "0x" represent in the MAC address?** When I first set mine up I was confused about that. As soon as I added the "0x" in front, everything started tweeting with no problems. I was just curious if this was a parity bit or some sort of place holder or what.

Comment: "0x" usually means that the following numbers or characters are Hex based. Otherwise the compiler will be way confused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a library available for twittering [here](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/TwitterLibrary), it has info on how to set it up.  I am not sure about how to use the ethernet sheild as I am too broke to afford one, but I imagine it wouldn't be that hard with the library installed.

This is the example code from the library page (looks nice and easy):

```
/* Post a simple message to Twitter  */
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <Twitter.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte ip[] = { 10, 0, 0, 177 };
byte gateway[] = { 10, 0, 0, 1 };
byte subnet[] = { 255, 255, 0, 0 };

Twitter twitter("YourID:Password");
char msg[] = "Hello, World! I'm Arduino!";

void setup()
{
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("connecting ...");
  if (twitter.post(msg)) {
    int status = twitter.wait();
    if (status == 200) {
      Serial.println("OK.");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed : code ");
      Serial.println(status);
  }
  } else {
  Serial.println("connection failed.");
  }
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Comment: Does the work since twitter moved to oauth?

Answer (score 0):

Have written what is hopefully a [simple explanation](http://tronixstuff.wordpress.com/2011/03/08/moving-forward-with-arduino-%E2%80%93-chapter-30-%E2%80%93-twitter/) on how to send a tweet with Arduino and an ethernet shield.